# Reading C comma separated hex file into python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to read a C Comma separated array file
into a python list and do some operations
on the data before sending it to another file.
Any ideas on how to do this while ignoring the comments ?

```
// Example file data.h
unsigned const short font_5x7[480] = {
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, //
    0x00,0x00,0xfa,0x00,0x00, // !
    0x00,0xe0,0x00,0xe0,0x00, // "
    0x28,0xfe,0x28,0xfe,0x28, // #
    0x24,0x54,0xfe,0x54,0x48, // $
    0xc4,0xc8,0x10,0x26,0x46, // %
etc.....
```

Comment: You want a C parser?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this

```
(?<data>[^/]*?)[ ]*//[^\n]*([\n\r]|())
```

Now in the "data" group there is essentialy this

```
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0xfa,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0xe0,0x00,0xe0,0x00,
0x28,0xfe,0x28,0xfe,0x28,
0x24,0x54,0xfe,0x54,0x48,
0xc4,0xc8,0x10,0x26,0x46,
```

You just need to itterate through all the matches and paste it in a string

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a position to access the code and a C compiler it may be easier to write a small C program to output the data in a nicer format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<480; i++)
    printf("%i\n", font_5x7[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
(0x\d+),
```

to capture hex number globally.

then

```
int(hex_num, 16)
```

to turn them into integer.